# Can you navigate away from the updates screen during an update?

Tags: dashboard, updates

Bit of a *random* question, I was running an update on a plugin, and went to <kbd>⌘</kbd> + **click** another item from the the dashboard menu, finger slipped and I ended up going straight to that page before the updates had finished.

I immediately went to the updates screen and the update had *gone*. I checked for updates just in case, but nothing. After looking in plugin changelog I can confirm it did update.

So my question is, do you have to sit through the update screen? Or is it enough to just "start the process" and you can click away to other pages on the dashboard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, server do not need any user input to complete the update, and once the request was received by the server it do not terminate it even if the connection to the browser had died (this is why it is actually impossible to cancel operations once started). Still it is probably better to leave it open to make sure the update was successful.

Comment: Yeah, as I was typing this up I thought that would probably be the only reason to leave it open, in case of any errors/messages.

Comment: You wouldn't happen to have a reference (codex or similar) confirming this Mark?

Comment: This is basic networking and web server fact, not really related in any way to wordpress itself.

Comment: Aha, gotcha! Was just looking for _evidence_ before marking as correct answer ;)

Comment: This can't be right... I just broke a wordpress website by navigating away from the update page, while the update was still running. The maintenance mode was then stuck permanently. I had to manually delete the `.maintenance` file. Happened on wordpress 5.5.3. Note that I was updating several plugins at once, maybe that makes a difference.

Comment: very much right and the `.maintenance` file should clear in 10 minutes from creation.